# multiple inbound in one flow mule esb

Tags: java, http, ftp, mule, esb

I need to create one esb flow.

1. first use http inbound to post json.
2. on basis of post json I get filename.
3. fetch that file from ftp server.
4. drop that file to another ftp server
5. call external api

is we can do this using esb?

I am using first http-inbound to post json then
ftp-inbound to fetch file but I am getting error?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use http inbound and ftp inbound or any other inbound together in same flow directly..

Multiple inbound endpoints can be called in a same flow by using **Mule Requester**.

Using this **Mule Requester**, you can call any inbound endpoints in the same flow. Please check this for your reference :- http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-the-mule-requester-module/  and **examples** to use it :- https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester/blob/master/mulerequesterdemo/src/main/app/MuleRequesterDemo.xml